# Google Sheets Regex Result Not Equal To Text

Tags: regex, google-sheets, comparison

I have a spreadsheet which i'm using for importing prices using `IMPORTHTML`.

The import result contains the prices with text.
I'm using `REGEXEXTRACT` to get the price only.
The problem is that the extraction is not equal to same value in other cell.

**For exmaple:**
The import result is:

$58.00 & *FREE Shipping*. Details

**in cell A1** - using `REGEXEXTRACT`with regular_expression "[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]" the result is *58.00*

**in cell A2** - i typed *58.00*

trying to compare the two (using `IF(A1=A2...`) will fail.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Enclose your own `REGEXEXTRACT` with another one: `=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(...),"^\W*([\d.]+)")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is that a solution for the problam or only an improvment to my regex syntax?

Comment: Try it and if it works, I will post with the explanations. It is not any improvements, it is another extraction function meant to grab the first float/integer from the value extracted with your regex. Actually, I can't make out what your approach looks like - could you share the sheet or just something similar to debug?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, i used your regex inside the answer below

Comment: So, you used `=VALUE(REGEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(<CELL1>, "[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]"),"^\W*([\d.]+)")=<CELL2>`?

Comment: no, i used =VALUE(REGEXTRACT(A1,"^\W*([\d.]+)") and then compared with IF condition

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following regex extraction:

```
REGEXEXTRACT(<CELL>, "^\W*([\d.]+)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LLuslk/1)

The `"^\W*([\d.]+)"` means:

- `^` - start of string
- `\W*` - zero or more non-word chars (non letters, digits, underscores)
- `([\d.]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits or dots.

As per Rubén's details, you need to cast the string value extracted with the `REGEXEXTRACT` to the actual value of the extracted text with `=VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

## Formula

Try

```
=VALUE(REGEXTRACT(A1,"[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]")=A2
```

## Explanation

REGEXEXTRACT always returns a text value. If you type 58.00 it's very likely that it's was identified as a number.

Comment: Thanks! your answer combined with @WiktorStribiżew answer gave me the best solution

Comment: Remember to upvote the helpful posts. Also consider to post an answer to share with other the best solution for you.

Comment: He can't upvote, so I did it for him since it is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this is:

```
=VALUE(REGEXTRACT(<CELL1>,"^\W*([\d.]+)")
```

and after that using:

```
IF(A1=A2...)
```